# Extract css styles from html document to external css file

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, extract

Is there a way to extract hardcoded styles in html documents to external css file ? If not, do you have an idea on how to do this? Have you ever done it before ?

Example, from:

```
<div style="background-color: red">
<a style="font-weight: bold"></a>
</div>
```

to

```
<div id='st-01'>
<a id='st-02'><a/>
</div>

#st-01 { background-color: red }
#st-02 { font-weight: bold }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly what you are looking for but if you don't mind copying and pasting your HTML, try this. Not too many features but it does the job!

http://extractcss.com/

https://github.com/peterlazzarino/Inline-CSS-Extractor

Answer (score 0):

You can use some JS/JQuery code to extract the styles, clear them, give elements an ID and add up css.
Check this example, you may extend it further.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 0;
    var css = "";
    $("div,a").each(function(){
        $(this).attr("id","st-"+i);
        css += "#"+$(this).attr("id")+"{"+$(this).attr("style")+"}";
        $(this).removeAttr("style");
        i++;
    });
    $("style").html(css);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d8TaJ/